# Solve limit without L'Hopital (unknown function)

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to do an exercise but I honestly don't know what to do to solve it. I know this will be a very basic question, but I'm learning limits.

The exercise is:

Given:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x) - 6}{x^2-4} = 5$$

Find: $$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} f(x)$$

I tried separating the limit but I didn't get anything from it.

If you could please help me understand what to do, I'd be greatful (I need to understand, not just the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)-6}{x^2-4}=5,$$you have\begin{align}\lim_{x\to2}f(x)-6&=\lim_{x\to2}\left(\frac{f(x)-6}{x^2-4}(x^2-4)\right)\\&=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)-6}{x^2-4}\times\lim_{x\to2}(x^2-4)\\&=5\times0\\&=0.\end{align}So, $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)=6$.

Comment: Thank you! but what if I was asked a different limit? for instance $\lim\limits_{x \to 3} f(x)$ ?

Comment: Then the answer would be $31$.

Comment: but how would you do it? This example with limit x -> 3 is just a random number I typed, not an exercise I have. I just want to understand this throughly

Comment: I wrote $31$ assuming that what you had in mind was that $\lim_{x\to3}\frac{f(x)-6}{x^2-4}=5$. Am I right?

Comment: Oh no, I meant if I'm given the same equation (with x -> 2) but then asking me for the limit of f(x) when x -> 3 (I have an exercise where they change the limit like this, but obviously with a different equation)

Comment: Then I do not have enough information to answe your question. In fact, I have no way of knowing whether or not the limit $\lim_{x\to3}f(x)$ even exists.

Comment: Hm... Then why can they ask me that in this exercise? Given $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x) - 8}{x-1} = 10$, find $\lim\limits_{x \to 8} f(x)$

Comment: They can't (or, at least, they shouldn't).

Comment: @JohnMyers: if you get such a question in exam please write out explicitly that there is insufficient information to solve the problem and perhaps there is a typo and the question should be (write the corrected version).